# Is using 'should' to omit 'if there is' appropriate?

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

I'm learning through an English app. It says there, to omit **if** in this sentence below:

> **If there is** a fire, leave the room.

I can use **in case**, so, the sentece will be:

> **In case** of fire, leave the room.

There's no further explanation since it has limited materials. I wonder whether I can use **should** just like when we omit **if** in an *action present simple if-clause*  like this:

> **Should there** a fire, leave the room.[1]

By the way, if I can use **should**, is [1] correct? Or, perhaps I should write:

> **Should there be** a fire, leave the room.[2]

Or

> **Should be there** a fire, leave the room.[3]

Which one is correct? Or what is the correct sentence if none of them is grammatically correct?

Comment: ***Should you be interested***, it's worth noting that this kind of "stylised inversion" normally only occurs in "literary" contexts. In more "natural" contexts it's usually ***If you're interested...*** (with or without the contraction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't omit "be" here when you're using "should".

"**Should there be** a fire" is the correct inverted form of "if there should be a fire" / "if there is a fire".

In a public notice, you would be better sticking with "in case of" or "if there is", because these are simpler formulations. This kind of important safety notice should be easily read and understood by as large an audience as possible, including by non-native speakers who may be unfamiliar with "should". Literary elegance isn't the goal.